# Roots of irreducible polynomial in finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $p(x)\in \mathbb F_{p}[x]$, irreducible of degree $n$. Show that $\alpha, \alpha^{p}, ..., \alpha^{p^{n-1}}$ are distinct roots of $p(x)$.

I can use the property that $a^{p}=a,a\in \mathbb{F}_{p}$ and $(a+b)^{p}=a^{p}+b^{p},a,b\in \mathbb{F}_{p}$ to prove that  $\alpha, \alpha^{p}, ..., \alpha^{p^{n-1}}$ are indeed the roots of $p(x)$. But I have a hard time figuring out that these roots are distinct.

Comment: Don't call it $p(x)$...

Comment: Careful: you can use $\;a^p=a\;$ **only if** $\;a\in\Bbb F_p\;$ , in *this case* it is true that $\;\alpha\notin\Bbb F_p\;$ as this last is a root of an **irreducible** polynomial in $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ and, obviously, the roots cannot be in $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ .

Comment: Yes, as DonAntonion mentioned, you meant $(a+b)^p = a^p + b^p$ for any $a,b \in K$ a field or domain of characteristic $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that any irreducible polynomial in $F_p[X]$ must be separable. So the roots of $p(x)$ are all distinct. We have $F_p[\alpha]:F_p=n$. Suppose $\alpha^{p^i}=\alpha^{p^j}$ then we have $\alpha^{p^k}=\alpha$ for some $k<n$ and so $\alpha$ belongs to the splitting field of $X^{p^k}-X$ over $F_p$ .Then we have $F_p[\alpha]:F_p≤k<n$ a contradiction.

Comment: I think we don't need separability, we are proving it. By unicity of finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) = \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(h(x)) = \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. So $\alpha \not \in  \mathbb{F}_{p^m}, m < n$. But as you said, if the $n$ roots are not all different then $\alpha = \alpha^{p^k} $ , ie. $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ the splitting field of $X^{p^k}-X$

Comment: Yes I observed that. But proving separability was pretty trivial so I decided to keep it

Comment: Why is it trivial ? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Well because the map $x \rightarrow x^p$ is an automorphism in $F_p$

Comment: I don't get it. I think we just proved the separability, and it wasn't so trivial.

Comment: We proved more than that. We showed the precise roots. For separability we just observe that $F_p$ is a perfect field and any irreducible polynomial $f(X)$ can be written as $g(X^{p^k})$ where $g(X)$ is separable.